# Why is the paragraph not floating beside the profilePic?

Tags: html, css, css-float

Somehow, the paragraph is not floating beside the profilePic. It starts from the bottom of the profilePic. I am not able to understand why.

What is the mistake here?

```css
.content {
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.infoBit {
  width: 800px;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
.profilePic {
  border: 1px blue solid;
  height: 49px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 49px;
  float: left;
}
.infoText {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="infoBit">
    <div class="profilePic"></div>
    <div class="infoText">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam quis enim ut sapien sodales commodo. Fusce congue, elit a finibus fermentum, diam eros mollis massa, at eleifend sapien dui eget mauris. Donec nec diam enim. Vivamus commodo placerat risus
        vitae auctor. Cras leo elit, egestas eget dolor vitae, facilisis consequat sem. Mauris facilisis ipsum in porttitor ullamcorper. Nam vel massa sed quam venenatis facilisis. Quisque vitae mollis urna. In egestas nunc sed felis consequat, in malesuada
        dolor feugiat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4sbzos1r/

Comment: Why are you wrapping the paragraph in `<div class="infoText">`?

Comment: @j08691: Yes , removing the div fixes it, but I don't understand why?

Comment: The problem boils down to the text in your infoText div being wrapped in an element (virtually any element). The browser can't take the container, in this case the paragraph, and bend it around the floated profilePic div -- it can do that with the text itself, but not the container. So if your text was only a single line, it's fine, and able to float next to the image because no calculation needs to be done. But once you have more than a single line of text, the browser throws its hand in the air and moves everything below the floated profilePic div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned, it is because you have your `<p>` wrapped in a `<div>` with class `infoText`, which applies the styling `display: inline-block; float:left;` from the css you wrote. I would suggest either taking out the `<div>` entirely, or just remove the `infoText` styling you have. Furthermore, you probably want `margin-top:0` on `.infoText` to bring the text to the top.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Why isn't the text aligned with the top of the profile pic?

Comment: The text is not aligned with the top of the profile pic because of the default styling for a `<p>` tag. Try putting style: `margin-top:0;` onto the p tag and it will pull it to the top, aligned with the picture

Comment: I was asking why the <p> tag not aligned? Could you give me more explanation or links to understand?

Comment: The `<p>` tag is not aligned to the top of the picture, because of the default styling `-webkit-margin-before: 1em;` in Chrome. You need to override that in order for it to be aligned to the top. It is because of things like this that people will often use `<span>` or even `<div>` when they put text in places and they need to be sure there won't be any default styling. The `<p>` tag was created for a specific purpose and will be rendered with default styles.

Answer (score 2):

It works fine even if

is wrapped inside a . Defining width of  resolves issue
Please  change styles as below

```
.content
{
    margin-top : 30px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}    

.infoBit
{
    width: 800px;
    /* float: left; */
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.profilePic
{
    border:1px blue solid;
    height: 49px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 49px;
    float: left;
}

.infoText
{
    display: inline-block;
  width: 700px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

hope this help you

```css
    .content
    {
     margin-top : 30px;
     margin-left: 20px;
     padding-bottom: 20px;
    }    
    
    .infoBit
    {
     width: 800px;
     float: left;
     display: inline-block;
     font-size: 1.1em;
     padding-right: 10px;
     padding-top: 10px;
    }
    
    .profilePic
    {
     border:1px blue solid;
     height: 49px;
     display: inline-block;
     width: 49px;
     float: left;
    }
    
    .infoText
    {
     display: inline-block;
      width:250px
    }
.infoText p{
  margin-top:0
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
      <div class="infoBit">
       <div class="profilePic"></div>
       <div class="infoText">
        <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam quis enim ut sapien sodales commodo. Fusce congue, elit a finibus fermentum, diam eros mollis massa, at eleifend sapien dui eget mauris. Donec nec diam enim. Vivamus commodo placerat risus vitae auctor. Cras leo elit, egestas eget dolor vitae, facilisis consequat sem. Mauris facilisis ipsum in porttitor ullamcorper. Nam vel massa sed quam venenatis facilisis. Quisque vitae mollis urna. In egestas nunc sed felis consequat, in malesuada dolor feugiat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
          </p>
        </div>
         </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Why isn't the paragraph by default not aligned with the top of the profile pic? i.e, why do we need the margin-top: 0

Comment: No, for aligned we need  to give width only. I add margin also because p also start from top same as profile pic.